# No postback after Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

This element

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ItemDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnChange="setHidden()" .... >
```

Doesn't do postback when I use OnChange attribute. Even if I do it manually:

```
function setHidden() {
  ...
  ...
  _doPostBack("","");
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use return statement instead of doing post back.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ItemDropDownList"  runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" 
     OnChange="return setHidden()" .... >

function setHidden() {
     ...
     ....
    return true; // you can return false to stop postback
}
```