# Fire postback after javascript validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms, postback

I have the following aspx code:

```
<td>
    <p>Customer*</p>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxCustomer" list="SiteMainContent_Customers" runat="server" OnTextChanged="CustomerTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" required CssClass="form-control" />
    <datalist id="Customers" runat="server"></datalist>
</td>
<td class="auto-style1">
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorKunde" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxCustomer"
        CssClass="Error" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomCustomerValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxCustomer" ErrorMessage="Customer not in CRM"
        OnServerValidate="ValidateCustomer" CssClass="Error"></asp:CustomValidator>
</td>
```

The custom validator:

```
public void Validate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        GetCompanyId(args.Value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ((CustomValidator)source).ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }
    args.IsValid = true;
}
```

The code is a snippet of my whole aspx page.
If some of the other field's doesnt validate and you have to correct the data, the `TextBoxCustomer` does not postback to the codebehind anymore.

What can I do to get TextBoxCustomer to postback, even if I have clicked Submit and the data in the fields did not validate?

It is somewhat related to [No postback after Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989419/no-postback-after-javascript-function) - I think it is because the validations return false.

Comment: Can i see your `ValidateCustomer` function?

Comment: @RameshRajendran I have added the custom validator to the answer. ValidateCustomer just calls this validate method.
But I do not think the custom validator gets called because the client side scripts blocks it before it checks serverside.

Answer (score 0):

Add `EnableClientScript="False"` to all validation controls

Comment: So it is not possible to get the testbox to postback without removing all clientside validation?